# how to declare UIPageControl inside class

Tags: swift3, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to add pageControl to my collection View which is inside my collectionView Cell, so I need to declare UIPageControl so

```
let CollectionViewPageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return pageControl
}
```

but I got this error  `Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'UIPageControl'`

so any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `collectionViewPageControl` as an `UIPageControl`, but you're assigning a closure to it.

You can do this:

```
let collectionViewPageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
collectionViewPageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)
collectionViewPageControl.currentPage = 0
collectionViewPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
collectionViewPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

You can read more about closures in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

And don't forget to add it to your `collectionViewCell` (or whatever is the parent of the `UICollectionView` that will be paginated).

```
yourCollectionViewCell.addSubview(collectionViewPageControl)
```

Comment: Don't forget `self.addSubview(collectionViewPageControl)`.

Comment: Of course, I just deduced OP is having problem only on the declaration of the `UIPageControl`, since that's the only code he posted. But I'll edit the answer anyway :)